# ¿Cómo rellenar datos faltantes de un CSV?

Tags: python, jupyter

alguien puede ayudarme de como rellenar datos faltantes de un archivo.csv.

La idea es primeramente recorrer la fila y si valor de la variable esta vacio realizar un promedio siempre y cuando el parametro de minuto no supere los 30 minuto, caso contrario poner NAN.

este codigo realiza una media de todo campos vacio pero la idea es tener en cuenta los minutos donde no haya datos

**

```
df['VelVto'].fillna(df['VelVto'].mean(), inplace=True)
df.isna().sum().sort_values()
```

**

```
    Date / Time         Vel.Viento
02/02/2022 14:30    2.400
02/02/2022 14:40    1.600
02/02/2022 14:50    
02/02/2022 15:00    2.100
02/02/2022 15:10    2.100
02/02/2022 15:20    1.700
02/02/2022 15:30    
02/02/2022 15:40    
02/02/2022 15:50    
02/02/2022 16:00    2.300
02/02/2022 16:10    2.900

**RESULTADO DESEADO**

Date / Time         Vel.Viento
02/02/2022 14:30    2.400
02/02/2022 14:40    1.600
02/02/2022 14:50    **1.407841**
02/02/2022 15:00    2.100
02/02/2022 15:10    2.100
02/02/2022 15:20    1.700
02/02/2022 15:30    **NAN**
02/02/2022 15:40    **NAN**
02/02/2022 15:50    **NAN**
02/02/2022 16:00    2.300
02/02/2022 16:10    2.900
```

Comment: Debido a la falta de reputación no puedo comentar tu pregunta, pero viendo los datos que proporcionas, la salida que esperas y la pregunta que formulas; diría que en algún lado de has equivocado (el primer valor vacío, a las `14:50`, según dices debería aparecer como NaN). En cualquier caso, no necesitas complicarte, tienes ya la parte difícil del código. ¿Por qué no simplemente después de sustituir los valores vacíos por la media añades otra línea que vuelva a sustituir por `NaN` todos los valores cuya columna `Date / Time` tenga el minuto > 30? De esta forma:

Comment: df['VelVto'].fillna(df['VelVto'].mean(), inplace=True)
df.loc[
    df['Date / Time'].minute >= 30, # Esto depende del tipo de datos de la columna
    'VelVto'
] = np.nan

Comment: te explico un poco mejor por ejemplo el valor para la fechaHora  "02/02/2022 14:50" inicialmente está vacio, pero como el rango de datos faltante es apenas de 10 minuto en ese caso hacer la media, pero supongase para "02/02/2022 15:20    1.700 " y "02/02/2022 16:00    2.300" aca el rango de hora es aca 40 minutos osea en ese caso ya es cosiderable los datos que falta y aca poner NAN, no se si me explique un poco mejor